# Easy way to capture Change in Model Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I Have below Model class .

```
 public class Activity_DemographicsViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Activity_Id { get; set; }

    public int RegionId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Activity Name")]
    public string Activity { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Activity Date"),  DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ActivityDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date Entered"), DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Region")]
    public string RegionOrganization { get; set; }

    public string Action { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Organization")]
    public string ActivityOrganization { get; set; }

    public int? ActivityOccurrence_Id { get; set; }


    public bool saveandcontinue { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LastChgDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Occurrence Date")]
    public DateTime OccuranceDate { get; set; }

    public string LastChgUserId { get; set; }

    public bool? NoNewParticipants { get; set; }

}
```

Infact i have to create many other objects inside this class around 30 more get ; set;

I am writing these values in to History tables while updating.

My question is there a simple and small code way where i write in to History only if any of these objects in this model (45 Objects) is changed from the previous values while saving . ??

I don't want to write in to History if user simply clicks update button with out changing the model values.

Answer (score 1):

Use reflection or 
You can use this nuget package
https://github.com/GregFinzer/Compare-Net-Objects/wiki/Getting-Started